# Can I set up a seperated addressbook from the deafult one for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, contacts, abaddressbook

can I set up a seperated addressbook from the deafult one for iPhone ?

I need this because for the app I am developing I need to add contact information for some special events; also I need to add contact information from work. I don't want to mix these contacts with the default addressbook(and I have other way to sync them). So is there a way to do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to create your own app? if so you can create one and store the data in SQLite. But if you want to use your own addressbook and have it coexist you may have a problem.

Comment: Yes I am creating my own app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two approaches by which the process could be done in your case first- there is no way that if you create a contact and when you sync it with the address book it will be saved in the address book data base and the contact will be there nothing the way that you add a contact in your app and the contact only highlight in your app only because the addressbook having only one database and adding and deleting contacts will effect the global database of the addresbook.Second thing you can maintain the your app database by which you can make the UI and the other part of the app like addressbook of iphone and just save those contacts in your database not in the addresbook database.Only these ways you have.